# Trouble Partition Hard Drive

Tags: windows, macos, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1

In my PC I currently have a 1TB hard drive that I am trying to make into three partitions: one for Windows, one for OS X, and one as a storage for movies and Steam games, just to keep them separated. I know I could get away with two but I think three will be more organized.

Anyways, first I got both OS X and Windows partitions up and running, with ~400 GB for OS X and ~600GB for Windows (this was before I decided I wanted a third partition). So I figured now I could just shrink both my Windows and OS X partitions and then merge the unallocated space into a new partition. In Windows, I shrunk my partition down top 300GB and it worked fine. Then I booted into OS X to shrink that partition to 200GB, also worked fine, but it was showing that my Windows partition was still 600GB, not the 300 I shrunk it to. Figuring this was just a bug, I booted back into Windows only to see that my C: drive was back to 600GB, but this time it won't let me shrink it anymore. Going to the C: drive properties shows that is only 300GB but in Disk Management it says it is nearly 600.

I tried to make a GParted Live USB stick using both tuxboot and by burning the iso directly but both get stuck on the message "waiting for /dev to be fully populated". I have tried some fixes for this but to no avail.

In short, Disk Management says my C: drive is 600GB when in fact it is only 300. Does anybody know how to recover the other 300 into unallocated space? Thanks!

Edit: I just noticed that up top in Disk Management it shows my C: drive as 300GB but in the lower part where it shows partitions as boxes it still says 600. This just adds to the confusion as to where my 300GB of unallocated space went.

Answer (score 0):

Install `EaseUs Partition master` home PC version in windows. it's free When you will open it you will see all the partitions you have made and you can change according to your choice.

Play carefully...good luck !

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but when I try and shrink that partition by even one MB I get the error message "Not enough unallocated space before and after the partition for Move/Resize feature". Any thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure but this is may be due to scattered data you can defragment your drive before shrink..

Comment: I tried that also and it didn't change anything.

Comment: can you provide screenshot of disk management for more details ?

Comment: Yes, [here it is](http://i57.tinypic.com/16jesrl.jpg)

Comment: something gone bad ,First expand your c drive, it should look 600 GB (original Condition) after that try once again by shrinking. you can try the software I mentioned above it will make your problem so easy